# MatLab - Changing the lower limit only of the y axis of a histogram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to only change the lower limit of the y axis of a histogram, but let the upper limit be automatically determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first grab the `x` and `y` limits by [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html), then resetting the `y` component to be whatever you want.  For a 2D plot (histogram in your case), this will be a four element vector where the first two elements are the lower and upper `x` limits and the last two elements will be the lower and upper `y` limits.

The lower limit of the `y` axis will be third element, and so you can set this to be whatever you want, then call `axis` again with this vector.  Assuming your figure is already open, do this:

```
v = axis;
v(3) = ...; %// Set to whatever limit you want
axis(v); %// Re-set the figure
```

## Example

Suppose I have this figure:

```
x = 1:20;
y = 2*x;
plot(x,y);
```

[image]

Let's say I wanted to drop the lower limit of `y` to be -20.... and so:

```
v = axis;
v(3) = -20;
axis(v);
```

We now get this:

[image]

Notice that the `x` limits are the same, and the upper bound of `y` is the same, but the lower bound has dropped.